# How to delete a record in octobercms?

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

I am a bit confused how it comes together. I am trying to delete a record from a list of records and I currently have this.

```
function onDelete()
{
$recordId = post('record')
$record = Advert::find($recordId); 
$record->delete();

}
```

In twig i have

```
 <tbody>
     {% for post in posts %}



      <td><a href="{{ 'product-single'|page({ slug: post.slug }) }}" name = "record">{{ post.title }}</a></td>


      <td><button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" data-request ="onDelete" data-request-confirm="Are you sure" data-request-success="alert('Successfully Deleted')">Delete</button> </td>

    </tr>

    {% endfor %}

 </tbody>
```

I am currently having this error

> "Call to a member function delete() on null"

Comment: just use a `<input type="hidden"`

Comment: so you are passing slug as your url parameter. and on you Controller you are looking as if it was an id. You would probably have to do something like `Advert::where('slug' ,request('post'))->first()->delete()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not sending the record ID to the server in your AJAX request.

Add `data-request-data="record: {{ post.id }}"` to your `button` that triggers the AJAX request so that `post('record')` actually gets data from the AJAX request that it can use to find the record that you want to delete.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use field names when querying. 
Try this.

```
function onDelete()
{
$recordId = request('post')
Advert::where('slug',$recordId)->delete(); 
}
```

If not add die() and use print_r to check whether Advert::where is returning any object.